# Diagnosing essential Classical Mathematical Analysis I knowledge needed for II

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, continuity, learning

I need to take Classical Mathematical Analysis II (Chapters 7-10:  Sequences & Series of Functions, Special Functions (Exp/Log/Fourier/Gamma), Functions of Several Variables, Integration of Differential Forms ).

How and what should I focus my review on the material to get up to speed for this course that just started?  What diagnostic testing would be wise?

Rudin's textbook is often mentioned as not ideal for self study.  What should I supplement it with?

EDIT: I read this helpful question on the self-study textbooks for Analysis:  [How can I pick up analysis quickly?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067304/how-can-i-pick-up-analysis-quickly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider:

Elementary Analysis: The Theory of Calculus (by Ross), and Spivak's Calculus

I'm not really sure why Rudin's is still the standard text...anyway

Comment: Oh that book I already have from an earlier lower level course, taking a look...

Answer (score 1):

Spivak as mentioned previously would be  a good way to revise with some supplemental material on metric spaces.

I find the ideal situation would be to  retake the first semester and then take the second semester immediately after.

Comment: The course is only offered once a year, which would delay me to 2017