# What is real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis

In some of my previous questions, I have noticed that something "real analysis" tends to come up. From context, it seems to be the analysis of real valued function's graphs. However, this confuses me. I thought *Calculus* was the study of graphs of functions?

Now I'm not asking for a detailed description of real analysis. A simple description will do fine.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/63735/589.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither calculus nor real analysis  is the study of the graphs.  Both study the properties of functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, particularly with regards to differentiation and integration.

An *application* of these studies is to graphs of functions, e.g. local maxima, concavity.

Generally real analysis is considered a theoretical subject, with rigorous proofs, while calculus is more about the calculation/computation.

Comment: For example: in calculus the intermediate value theorem might be essentially taken as an axiom, whereas in analysis you spend 20 pages defining what a number is in order to be able to prove it as a theorem.

Comment: Calculus, both integral as well as differential, constitutes a part of the much larger domain of mathematical analysis. The relationship is thus one of inclusion. The same goes for real analysis, which, along with complex analysis, also forms a part of the same. The relationship between the two sub-domains, however, is one of intersection, since each has parts not belonging to the other.