# Ways to write mind maps to study math

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

I asked this question earlier: [How should someone remember theorems?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3817225/how-should-someone-remember-theorems) and the last answer made me think about drawing mind maps to study math. I usually don't take notes because (as I said in a comment of that question) I think it's a little too slow and a little pointless since everything is written down in the textbook already and I can highlight the important parts and just read those, a mind map is different though and it can be pretty useful. I once made a very big mind map of mechanics and electromagnetism and it turned out super useful, but math is different, I don't really know how I should do it. Do you guys ever study using mind maps? How do you do it? To be more clear let me ask some questions: Should I include proofs in this mind map? How can I connect the "nodes" if so many topics in math overlap? Should I do it for a whole field or maybe just some specific topics?
The answer in the question I linked above sounds like a good idea, connect the nodes (or vertices etc of the mind map), representing axioms and theorems, to other theorems that are proved using these previous theorems (pretty much just like math works, tarts from axioms, prove theorems and from these prove other theorems), this sounds good but I think it's a little hard to implement. You guys have any idea?

Comment: Funny how people like the question but it's been closed anyway.. it's been closed because "This question is not about mathematics" lol what is it about then? There are hundreds of questions asking for study advices that are not closed

Comment: Try this site instead: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/